# How to create 2 VPN interfaces simultaneously?

Tags: java, android

In [VpnService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html), I create a VPN interface tun0 using java code below:

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

Builder builder = new Builder();

builder.addAddress("10.8.0.2", 20);
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);

mInterface = builder.establish();
```

When I want to create second tun use code below:

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface, mInterface2;

Builder builder = new Builder();
Builder builder2 = new Builder();

builder.addAddress("10.8.0.2", 20);
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
builder2.addAddress("10.8.0.3", 20);

mInterface = builder.establish();
mInterface2 = builder2.establish();
```

Second tun can create, but the first tun will close.

[Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html) is the helper class used for creating a VPN interface.

Can anyone give me some idea? 
How to create two tun simultaneously?

Comment: What is a tun ? TUN  = network TUNnel?

Comment: It is a virtual network interface

Comment: like this http://ppt.cc/3wAnW

Comment: What's the package name for Builder?

Comment: builder like this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html        tun=tun/tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the docs on VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) carefully.

You will note that you can't connect to multiple VPNs.

> Letting applications intercept packets raises huge security concerns.
>   A VPN application can easily break the network. Besides, two of them
>   may conflict with each other. The system takes several actions to
>   address these issues. Here are some key points:
>
> - **There can be only one VPN connection running at the same time. The
>     existing interface is deactivated when a new one is created.**

You can have only one at a time. But that doesn't mean you can't switch in between the two when you need to use the other.

---

**Update** - same holds for VPN interfaces . From [Builder docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#establish()):

> To avoid conflicts, there can be only one active VPN interface at the
>   same time.

Comment: but I only create the interface, not use VPN connection running.

Comment: I want to product the result tun0 tun1...use java code, but the tun1 will overwrite tun0, can't simultaneously product.

Comment: Same principle holds for Vpn Interface. To avoid conflicts, there can be only one active VPN interface at the same time - source http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#establish()

Comment: I think I can't use VpnService , I must use another method to create, thank you.

Comment: Can I ask some question? In java , what method I can use to create virtual interface? Have any mehod to reference?  Thank you.

Comment: You can add a new question if it's on topic.

Comment: @Mark that, i do not know. You can ask a new question for more attention on it.

Comment: Can ask a question?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#establish() mean "However, it is rare but not impossible to have two interfaces while performing a seamless handover. In this case, the old interface will be deactivated when the new one is created successfully. Both file descriptors are valid but now outgoing packets will be routed to the new interface." ,  so I can create two interface but only one active VPN interface at the same time ?